# How can I extract data as a list from a pandas.core.frame.DataFrame datatype?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas to make a DataFrame.

```
dfRating.insert(1, "count", mylist)
dfRating = dfRating.drop(columns= ['show_id', 'release_year'] )
dfRating = dfRating.groupby('rating').sum()
```

Now I want to take the data from this DataFrame into list. I've tried this.

```
for key, value in dfRating:
  list.append(key)
  list.append(value)
```

but i am getting an error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-918027fab8fd> in <module>()
      7 list = []
      8 
----> 9 for key, value in dfRating:
     10   list.append(key)
     11   list.append(value)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I tried just using one variable to iterate over (key) and it seems to only return the column titles. Here is the dataType:

```
type(dfRating)
```

pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: _Now I want to take the data from this DataFrame into list._ Why? What do you understand from that error message? Have you done any research, looked at the documentation? As an aside, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your command:

```
dfRating = dfRating.groupby('rating').sum()
```

Try this:

```
result_list = dfRating.values.tolist()
```